# Derivative of a smoothed curve

Tags: r, ggplot2, smoothing, derivative, gam

|  | point | doy |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.6917529 | 49 |
| 2 | 0.6917501 | 49 |
| 3 | 0.6917529 | 49 |
| 4 | 0.6917501 | 49 |
| 5 | 0.2857624 | 59 |
| 6 | 0.2857624 | 59 |
| 7 | 0.1809273 | 109 |
| 8 | 0.1808737 | 109 |
| 9 | 0.1809273 | 109 |
| 10 | 0.1808737 | 109 |
| 11 | 0.3589439 | 119 |
| 12 | 0.3588334 | 119 |
| 13 | 0.3589439 | 119 |
| 14 | 0.3588334 | 119 |
| 15 | 0.3589439 | 119 |
| 16 | 0.3588334 | 119 |
| 17 | 0.3362660 | 119 |
| 18 | 0.3365558 | 119 |
| 19 | 0.7751922 | 139 |
| 20 | 0.7751910 | 139 |
| 21 | 0.7751922 | 139 |
| 22 | 0.7751910 | 139 |
| 23 | 0.8126297 | 149 |
| 24 | 0.8126118 | 149 |
| 25 | 0.8126297 | 149 |
| 26 | 0.8126118 | 149 |
| 27 | 0.8251105 | 159 |
| 28 | 0.8251142 | 159 |
| 29 | 0.8251105 | 159 |
| 30 | 0.8251142 | 159 |
| 31 | 0.8403495 | 189 |
| 32 | 0.8403497 | 189 |
| 33 | 0.8403495 | 189 |
| 34 | 0.8403497 | 189 |
| 35 | 0.7746058 | 196 |
| 36 | 0.7746463 | 196 |
| 37 | 0.7746058 | 196 |
| 38 | 0.7746463 | 196 |
| 39 | 0.6160177 | 226 |
| 40 | 0.6160177 | 226 |
| 41 | 0.5651071 | 239 |
| 42 | 0.5651133 | 239 |
| 43 | 0.5651071 | 239 |
| 44 | 0.5651133 | 239 |
| 45 | 0.3736361 | 249 |
| 46 | 0.3736361 | 249 |
| 47 | 0.3366151 | 256 |
| 48 | 0.3365827 | 256 |
| 49 | 0.3366151 | 256 |
| 50 | 0.3365827 | 256 |

Using the above data, i am trying to apply GAM smoothing curve to the point column and also plot the smoothed curve with the derivative of the smooth on the same plot. I tried the following

```
ggplot(df, aes(doy)) +
    geom_line(aes(y=point),col='blue') +
    geom_smooth(aes(y=point),method = "gam", formula = y ~s(x,bs='cr'), size = 1, se = F, colour = "blue")
}
```

This got me only the smoothed curve and then i tried getting the values of the smoothed curve using:

```
library(mgcv)
mod = gam(point~s(n=doy,bs='cr'),data=df)
df$fitted = fitted(mod)
```

But i'm having issues getting and plotting the derivative as i have used:

```
derivatives(mod)

# And
fderiv(mod)


# Lastly
first_diff = function(x,y){
  vec=vector(length=length(x))
  vec[1]=0
  for (i in 2:length(x)){
    vec[i]=(y[i]-y[i-1])/(x[i]-x[i-1])
  }
  return(vec)
}
```

I was unable to come up with the derivative (rate of change of points with the day of the year) for the curve

Comment: You're not catering for the repeated values of `doy` when calculating the derivative.

Comment: Can you add the output of `dput(df)` to your question; it would make it much easier to see what the issue is as you don't say what the problem with `derivatives()` is - don't use `fderiv()` it was really only designed with simple time-series like AMs in mind. I can't see immediately what the issue is with `derivatives()` hence wanting the data in a useful format to run this myself without having to scrape a HTML table, but I suspect this is more a question of how to plot the results from `derivatives` rather than an error in `derivatives()` per se